# Replacing values in one data frame with values in a second data frame conditional on a logic statement

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames: "unit_test" with unique descriptions of survey units (one row per survey unit) and "data_test" with field data (multiple rows per survey unit). If it is a ground survey (data_test$type='ground'), I want to replace data_test$easting with the value in unit_test$east for the corresponding code (unit_test$code must match data_test$code1). If it is an air survey (data_test$type=='air'), I want to keep the original values in data_test$easting.

```
# Create units table
code <- c('pondA','pondB','pondC','pondD','transect1','transect2','transect3','transect4')
east <- c(12345,23456,34567,45678,NA,NA,NA,NA)
north <- c(99876,98765,87654,76543,NA,NA,NA,NA)
unit_test <- data.frame(cbind(code,east,north))
unit_test

# Create data table
code1 <- c('pondA','pondA','transect1','pondB','pondB','transect2','pondC','transect3','pondD','transect4')
type <- c('ground','ground','air','ground','ground','air','ground','air','ground','air')
easting <- c(NA,NA,18264,NA,NA,46378,NA,86025,NA,46295)
northing <-c(NA,NA,96022,NA,NA,85766,NA,21233,NA,23090)
species <- c('NOPI','NOPI','SCAU','GWTE','GWTE','RUDU','NOPI','GADW','NOPI','MALL')
count <- c(10,23,50,1,2,43,12,3,7,9)
data_test <- data.frame(cbind(code1,type,easting,northing,species,count))
data_test
```

I have tried using the match function:

```
if(data_test$type=="ground") {
data_test$easting <- unit_test$east[match(data_test$code1, unit_test$code)]
}
```

However it replaces the easting values if data_test$type=='air' with NAs. Any help would be much appreciated.

I want my final output to look like this:

```
       code1   type easting northing species count
1      pondA ground   12345    99876    NOPI    10
2      pondA ground   12345    99876    NOPI    23
3  transect1    air   18264    96022    SCAU    50
4      pondB ground   23456    98765    GWTE     1
5      pondB ground   23456    98765    GWTE     2
6  transect2    air   46378    85766    RUDU    43
7      pondC ground   34567    87654    NOPI    12
8  transect3    air   86025    21233    GADW     3
9      pondD ground   45678    76543    NOPI     7
10 transect4    air   46295    23090    MALL     9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R:

```
data_test[data_test$type == 'ground',c('easting','northing')] <- unit_test[match(data_test[data_test$type == 'ground','code1'],unit_test$code),c('east','north')]
```

Find the spots you want to fill, and make an index with match like you mentioned. This is after a change in your sample data. I used stringsAsFactors = F when creating both data frames so I didn't have to deal with factors.

Answer (score 2):

I think `data.table` package is really useful for this task:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

unit_test = data.table(unit_test)
data_test = data.table(data_test)
```

Add a column to `unit_test` specifying it refers to "ground":

```
unit_test$type = "ground"
```

Set keys to table in order to cross reference

```
setkey(data_test, code1, type, species)
setkey(unit_test, code, type)
```

Every time you have "ground" for type in `data_test`, lookup appropriate data in `unit_test` and replace `easting` with `east`

```
data_test[unit_test, easting:= east]
data_test[unit_test,northing:= north]
```

Results:

```
> data_test
        code1   type easting northing species count
 1:     pondA ground   12345    99876    NOPI    10
 2:     pondA ground   12345    99876    NOPI    23
 3:     pondB ground   23456    98765    GWTE     1
 4:     pondB ground   23456    98765    GWTE     2
 5:     pondC ground   34567    87654    NOPI    12
 6:     pondD ground   45678    76543    NOPI     7
 7: transect1    air   18264    96022    SCAU    50
 8: transect2    air   46378    85766    RUDU    43
 9: transect3    air   86025    21233    GADW     3
10: transect4    air   46295    23090    MALL     9
```